# How to invoke a method with objects as parameters?

Tags: java, object, parameter-passing

I am not understanding the Concept of Passing objects as parameters. Below is an example. My question is how can I invoke my PrintTime method? If my understanding is correct: the first method (Time) is a constructor with no parameters but the PrintTime is a method with an object as a parameter. How can I invoke it?

```
public class Time {

int hour, minute;
double second;

public Time() {
this.hour= 0;
this.minute= 0;
this.second= 0.0;
}

public static void printTime(Time t){
    System.out.println(t.hour+ ":"+ t.minute+ ":"+ t.second);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Time t1 = new Time();
    t1.hour= 11;
    t1.minute= 8;
    t1.second= 3.14159;
    System.out.println(t1);
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your main method you can call `printTime(t1);` 
The paramter t in your printTime method is an reference to the Time object you will pass into the method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `public Time() {`  is a constructor and

`public static void printTime(Time t){`

is a method, to call this method (you have defined static) you need to do:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Time t1 = new Time();
    t1.hour= 11;
    t1.minute= 8;
    t1.second= 3.14159;
    Time.printTime(t1);   /// <--< here  

}
```

Comment: Thank you! Just a little error. It should be:
      Time.printTime(t1);